# how to convert cv::Mat to json format in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv

```
-(void) processImage:(cv::Mat &)image{

    cvtColor(image, img2, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    orb -> detect(img2, keypoints1);

    orb -> compute(img2, keypoints1, descriptors1);

    drawKeypoints(img2, keypoints1, outImage);

}
```

OutImage is in cv::Mat format. How to convert it into NSDictionary format, using openCV ORB algorithm for my project.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your use-case here... You have an image (named "image"), you apply a keypoint detector, extract some descriptors and draw your keypoints on an image named ("outImage"). You'd like to return this image so you can draw it in the UI? If so, convert the cv::Mat object to a UIImage and set it as the UIImageView's "image" property. If that's the case, let me know and I will post the info as an answer. P.S: what version of OpenCV are you using?

Comment: Ya you are right.. i don`t know how to  draw the key points in the UI  while scanning the image.. and i want to send the outImage to server using client socket.. Can you please explain... I am using openCV 3.0

Comment: If you want i will send my whole code.. I used AVFoundation Framework for camera purpose.. Using SampleBufferData Function i just return the image as cv::Mat.. After that am doing the orb detect and extractions..  Thanks in advance.. -rhcpfan